# Python: Combine two lists, overwriting the final few lines of the first list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

This is a fairly simple question, but I am looking for the most Pythonic method of doing it. I have two lists:

```
a = [..., 5, 7, 4, 8]
b = [a, b, c, d]
```

I need to combine these two lists, overwriting the last 3 numbers of list `a`, such that it produces the following list:

```
c = [..., 5, a, b, c, d]
```

The `...` represent a varying length set of numbers, so ideally the method to do this would use a reference from the end of the list rather than the start (i.e. something along the lines of `a[-3]` rather than `a[27]`).

I have tried various `for` loops to cycle through the lists until it reaches the correct point, but this seems highly inefficient and I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing it.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a *new* list, use slicing and concatenation:

```
c = a[:-3] + b
```

Python slice notation allows for *negative* indices, interpreted as relative to the length of the list. `[:-3]` is the same as `[0:len(a) - 3]`; slicing everything but the last three elements.

You can also alter `a` in-place by assigning to a slice:

```
a[-3:] = b
```

replaces the last 3 elements of `a` with all elements of `b`.

Comment: Wow. I was looking for something complicated and missed the obvious. I did actually need to alter `a` in place, so `a[-3:] = b` has solved all my issues.
(You were very quick as well, not even allowed to accept this answer yet!)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd save the value 3 as a constant (to avoid magic numbers).

Then I'd simply use:

```
NUMBER_FROM_END = 3
c = a[:-NUMBER_FROM_END] + b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `list a` in-place, you can use `list's` class method `extend`.
1)

```
a = a[:-3]
a.extend(b)
```

2) you can reverse the list and again then use extend on it.

```
a = range(10)
b = range(11,20)
b = b[::-1] #reverse b 
b.extend(a[:-3][::-1]) #remove last 3 element of a and reverse it
b = b[::-1]   #again reverse b to get final result
```

Comment: Although that will only append the elements from another iterable. To replace the last three items and extend at the same time and in-place, a _slice assignment_ I think is best.

Comment: @RussW Thanks, and I also think slice will be better.